# Number of parameter for convolutional filter

Tags: conv-neural-network

Suppose you have a 10x10x3 colour image input and you want to stack two convolutional layers with kernel size 3x3 with 10 and 20 filters respectively. How many parameters do you have to train for these two layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of parameter for convolution layer can be calculated as

**(width x height x c<sub>in</sub> + bias) x c<sub>out</sub>**

For first layer parameter will be

```
(3 x 3 x 3 + 1) x 10 which is 280
```

Now for second layer

```
(3 x 3 x 10 + 1) x 20, here c_in 10 is from previous layer, so this layer 
have 1820 parameter
and total parameter is 1820 + 280 which is 2100
```